# websocket unable to connect on ec2 with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I am running node.js and socket.io on EC2, using nginx v1.4.1

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}


server {
        listen 80;

        server_name mysite.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4321;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
}
```

However I get 
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://mysite.com/socket.io/1/websocket/nS7f2eI5jAZ-pIN_8fai' failed: Unexpected response code: 502`

and from node:

```
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/nS7f2eI5jAZ-pIN_8fai
debug - set heartbeat interval for client nS7f2eI5jAZ-pIN_8fai
warn  - websocket connection invalid
```

Then it switches to xhr-polling.

I have followed exactly how so many online guides say about Nginx + websocket, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Did you try `http://127.0.0.1:4321` instead, just so that ipv6 isn't involved? Also, are you sure that node is listening to localhost and not just a specific IP address?

Comment: tried `http://127.0.0.1:4321`, didn't work. node is listening to `localhost:4321` :(

Comment: Does it work ok if you run node directly on port 80?

Comment: yes, if I run node as root, or if I visit port 4321 directly both works.

Comment: /etc/hosts has an entry that says 127.0.0.1 is localhost ?  Have you tried binding node to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?

Comment: Tried, but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/), you can try the following in your nginx config file.

```
   location /wsapp/ {
        proxy_pass                           http://your-host:your-port/;
        proxy_http_version                   1.1;
        proxy_set_header                     Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header                     Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header                     Host $host;
   }
```